# Beautifulsoup image downloading error

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download the images from the imageurls that come back from a Beautifulsoup scrape. I was trying to get this code to work after reading on some other examples tho the

Getting error: 
`f.write(requests.get(img))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Response`

line: `f.write(requests.get(img)[What goes here?])` is causing me trouble now. I use `soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')`

Where as the reference uses `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)`

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
import sys
import requests
from os.path  import basename

lines = open('list.txt').read().splitlines()
for designers in lines:
    for i in range(1):
        url = 'https://www.example.com/Listings?st=' + author + '{}'.format(i)
        source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
        for products in soup.find_all('li', class_='widget'):
            image = products.find('img', class_='lazy-load')

            print(image.get('data-src'))
            img = (image.get('data-src'))
            with open(basename(img), "wb") as f:
                f.write(requests.get(img)**[What goes here?]**)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to get the content out of the response. See documentation here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content.

Comment: Appreciate the response but im no further after looking at the link. The code there seems completely different than mine. `with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
        fd.write(chunk)`

Comment: Just use `f.write(requests.get(img).content)`

Comment: That worked!!! I swear I tried that and got an error before! Okay, how to I point where the image downloads to?